# Parsing the fbsr_cookie

Tags: php, facebook, cookies, authentication

I have implemented a Facebook connect example with my Codeigniter website. I am trying to bring the Facebook connect code up to date but I cannot work out how to parse the fbsr_cookie which has replaced the fbs_cookie.

I have the following code -

```
function get_facebook_cookie() 
    {
        // get the fb app id, and secret from CI config source
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $app_id = $CI->config->item('facebook_app_id');
        $application_secret = $CI->config->item('facebook_app_secret');
        if(isset($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id])){
            $args = array();
            parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
            ksort($args);
            $payload = '';
            foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
                    if ($key != 'sig') {
                    $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
                    }
            }
            if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
                    return null;
            }
            return $args;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and then to get the user's Facebook id -

```
function getUser()
    {
        $cookie = $this->get_facebook_cookie();
        $user = @json_decode(file_get_contents( 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' . $cookie['access_token']), true);
        return $user;
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can change this to work with the fbsr_cookie?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use FB PHP SDK?

Comment: I am using Codeigniter and Tank_auth to handle logging in. This is from an extension of Tank_auth that handles third-party login scripts. I thought by using this method it would make life easier.

Comment: @tom - I use Tank_auth and eric bae's XTA2 but this combo does not work anymore since FB changed a few things with their new oAuth 2.0 - I had some problems with the new cookie recently but managed to get this working with FB SDK - let me know if you solved this already and I can try to help

Comment: @torr - Yes I was using Tank_auth and Eric's XTA2 but realised that it wasn't working anymore unfortunately. I'm now trying the FB SDK but running into a problem with it returning 0 for getUser(). I followed a tutorial from here - http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/07/using-the-facebook-api-with-codeigniter to load the library. Can you give any info of how you've incorporated it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new cookie format with name `fbsr_APPID` is actually a `signed_request` which is quite easy to parse and documentation showing exactly how to do this (see "Verifying and Decoding" in [`signed_request` Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Answer (score 0):

That function looks just like the from codeigniter's XTA extension (now not maintained).  Not only do you have to change fbs_ to fbsr_, there is a completely different set of token parsing going on:

here is the updated function:

```
function get_facebook_cookie() {
     $CI =& get_instance();
     $app_id = $CI->config->item('facebook_app_id');
     $application_secret = $CI->config->item('facebook_app_secret');
      if(isset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id])){
         list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id], 2);

         $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
         $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

         if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
             return null;
         }
         $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload,
         $application_secret, $raw = true);
          if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
              return null;
          }
          $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
         . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&client_secret=" . $application_secret. "&redirect_uri=" . "&code=" . $data['code'];

          $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
          $params = null;
          parse_str($response, $params);
          $data['access_token'] = $params['access_token'];
          return $data;
      }else{
          return null;
     }
}
```

This came from this [useful blog post](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/oauth-20-facebook-changes-and-cookie-problem-in-codeigniter) with some other tidbits about the issue.

Also, insure that you have allow_url_fopen for the @file_get_contents call. The '@' will hide these errors.